# Is await considered a bad coding practice?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to asynchronous programming and I would like to know if using `await` is considered a bad coding practice. I am asking this because it looks like it is possible to let the callback function do the waiting instead of letting the entire program suspend everythng until the rpocess complete.

Thank you and I appreciate your idea on this.

Comment: Await allows you to write synchronous looking promises which are a wrap to standardize how we write callbacks. Please present a more concrete example because generalizing it with what you have asked is too broad.

Comment: The `await` keyword does not suspend everything until the process is complete. It only suspends the code after it. Basically `await` compiles the remainder of the function into a callback to `.then()`

Comment: Maybe take a look at the async/await section of [this article](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke#asyncawait)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it’s not. It’s just an approach (very useful sometimes).
In modern systems complexity is so high, that in many cases having clear code is much better that having super effective code. Just an example: imagine the case when you need to make several async things one by one (maybe, fetch data based one previously fetched results). You can do it making a chain of several `.then()`. After that you’ll need to also add `.catch()`. And at this point you’ll find yourself writing spaghetti code which is a bit messy.
The other option is just make this async function with sequential calls and some logic between them. And this will look much better